# How to Prevent MySQL UUID V1 Collision

Tags: mysql, uuid

Our API is designed to generate UUIDs in MySQL for all records.

However, 99% of the records being generated in all tables share the same last 3 blocks of the UUID. I'm assuming this is because MySQL uses v1 of UUID which is based on Mac address which doesn't change on the same server. It doesn't seem like enough entropy to have a high level of confidence in uniqueness.

e.g. XXXXXXXX-XXXX-46fc-bb08-f9b12276ed01

This is validated per Wikipedia:

"given the speed of modern processors, successive invocations on the same machine of a naive implementation of a generator of version 1 UUIDs may produce the same UUID, violating the uniqueness property. (Non-naïve implementations can avoid this problem by, for example, remembering the most recently generated UUID, "pocketing" unused UUIDs, and using pocketed UUIDs in case a duplicate is about to be generated.)"

It sounds like if enough API calls are made within a certain amount of time that collision would all be certain (just a matter of reaching transactional volume e.g. 1000 transactions a second? i.e. close to 1 transaction per millisecond).

Assumption: UUID() is function of the MySQL binary which cannot be changed.

**At what volume do I need to evaluate a change to prevent collisions and how would I make the wikipedia recommended change in MySQL to "pocket" UUIDs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a unique constraint on your UUID column.  That'll make the database check for duplicates before inserting (or updating) a record, so you can be sure there are no collisions in the table.  The colliding record will just fail to insert.

If you find that you're actually getting errors due to violation of that constraint — i.e. if collisions are *actually* happening in the UUID generator and the database is keeping them out of the table — then you can look into more sophisticated methods to generate a new UUID and try again.  But chances are, you won't have any problems.

The timestamp field in the UUID is measured in 100-nanosecond intervals, so you'd have to generate two UUIDs within a tenth of a microsecond to get a collision.  That corresponds to a rate of ten million transactions per second.  A thousand should be fine.

Comment: In addition to the timestamp there's also the clock-sequence, which seems to be seeded randomly; this is incremented every time a UUID is generated. 

This is effectively 10-bits, meaning you'd have to generate thousands of UUIDs per 100 nanosecond interval before you're in danger of a collision.

All a good UUID implementation should need to do is share this sequence between threads, and lock it for a few picoseconds to ensure no possibility of collision. Current hardware however shouldn't be fast enough to need this yet.

And remember, this is also per machine.

Comment: But that also means all the MAC part of the uuid is useless information and a waste of storage space, if you have only one or few machines, and that field could be reduced to a BINARY(6) instead of BINARY(16)